# What could cause the menu and playback to stop working on a D90?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d90

I was testing a lens—50mm—when I'd finally noticed that the menus stopped working. I couldn't get to Menu, Playback, INFO; I couldn't use the arrows and OK button to navigate on the image displayed right after I shot it.

Also, the LCD display is working fine, because liveview is. I really don't know why is this happening.

I didn't hit my camera with anything, I didn't let it get wet. It is working fine but for this. I've already tried to contact Nikon, but they couldn't help me.

I have tried everything: changing battery, changing lens, checking to see if any button wasn't stuck—but none of this helped.

Comment: Have you tried taking the lens off, and restarting things? Have you tried swapping lenses? It's an old camera - are you absolutely sure the buttons aren't stuck? Are the battery contacts clean? Are you on current Firmware? If none of that helps, do you have a photo repair shop in your area?

Comment: I can't update the firmware because I don't have access to the Menu. I welcome any sugestions.

Answer (score 3):

> What could cause the menu and playback to stop working on a D90?

The camera is broken.

You've already tried pretty much everything that you can as an end user to diagnose or reset the camera. Since it would cost far more than the camera is worth just to have it diagnosed, it is time for another camera.

Since you've got nothing much to lose at this point, if you're feeling adventurous pull of the back of the camera and check to see if it is something easy such as a loose ribbon cable going to the control pad (the arrows and OK buttons referenced in the question). Otherwise, it is probably time to move on.